# parsing though xml recursively using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, xml-parsing, xslt-grouping

I have an Xml as follows:

```
<Soap:Envelope>
<Soap:Body>
<A>
   <B>Text</B>
   <C>Text</C>
   <D>
      <D1>Text</D1>
      <D2>
          <D3>Text</D3>
          <D4>Text</D4>
      </D2>
   </D>
   <E>
      <E1>
          <E2>
              <E3>Text</E3>
          </E2>
      </E1>
   </E>
</A>
</Soap:Body>
</Soap:Envelope>
```

How do I recursively parse through all the tags(I only know that I will be receiving an xml template), know the tag names and the "Text" in them using XSLT? I need to store the data in the format as below.Below answer works fine when I don't have  and  tags. How to get the output now?

```
A_B = Text1
A_C = Text2
A_D_D1 = Text3
A_D_D2_D3 = Text4
A_D_D2_D4 = Text5
A_E_E1_E2_E3 = Text6
```

I know that we need to write a recursive function as below. That is where I need some help.

```
<for-each select="./*">
   //Recursive Function
</for-each>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your input shows `Text`, not `Text1`, `Text2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[text()]">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your example input, will return:

```
A_B = Text
A_C = Text
A_D_D1 = Text
A_D_D2_D3 = Text
A_D_D2_D4 = Text
A_E_E1_E2_E3 = Text
```

---

### Added:

Your new requirement is not defined well enough (and your new XML is not well-formed). If I am guessing correctly, you want to exclude any namespaced element names from the concatenated path. If so, replace:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
```

with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[not(namespace-uri())]">
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I am receiving different payloads with                  <SOAP-Envelope></SOAP-Envelope> and some other tags surrounding my xml. How do i remove them from the output?

Comment: @Raghavendra I am afraid I don't understand. Either edit your question and show an example of the input (along with the expected output), or post a new question.

Comment: need same output with the updated XML. The current answer gives the extra tags as we are using ancestor-or-self::*. Hopes his makes sense.

Comment: @Raghavendra See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need.